# What does the "Test of Epoch [number]" mean in Mozilla DeepSpeech?

Tags: speech-recognition, mozilla-deepspeech

What does the "Test of Epoch [number]" mean in Mozilla DeepSpeech?

In the following example, it says `Test of Epoch 77263`, even though there should be just 1 epoch from my understanding, since I gave `--display_step 1  --limit_train 1  --limit_dev 1  --limit_test 1 --early_stop False --epoch 1` as arguments:

```
dernoncourt@ilcomp:~/asr/DeepSpeech$ ./DeepSpeech.py --train_files data/common-voice-v1/cv-valid-train.csv,data/common-voice-v1/cv-other-train.csv --dev_files data/common-voice-v1/cv-valid-dev.csv --test_files data/common-voice-v1/cv-valid-test.csv --decoder_library_path /asr/DeepSpeech/libctc_decoder_with_kenlm.so --fulltrace True --display_step 1  --limit_train 1  --limit_dev 1  --limit_test 1 --early_stop False --epoch 1
W Parameter --validation_step needs to be >0 for early stopping to work
I Test of Epoch 77263 - WER: 1.000000, loss: 60.50202560424805, mean edit distance: 0.894737
I --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
I WER: 1.000000, loss: 58.900837, mean edit distance: 0.894737
I  - src: "how do you like her"
I  - res: "i "
I --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
I WER: 1.000000, loss: 60.517113, mean edit distance: 0.894737
I  - src: "how do you like her"
I  - res: "i "
I --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
I WER: 1.000000, loss: 60.668221, mean edit distance: 0.894737
I  - src: "how do you like her"
I  - res: "i "
I --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
I WER: 1.000000, loss: 61.921925, mean edit distance: 0.894737
I  - src: "how do you like her"
I  - res: "i "
I --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Explanation by Tilman Kamp](https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech/issues/1425#issuecomment-401841723):

> This is actually not a bug, as the current epoch is computed on base
>   of your current parameters and the snapshot-persisted global
>   step-count. Take a close look into this excerpt:
>
> ```
> # Number of GPUs per worker - fixed for now by local reality or cluster setup
> gpus_per_worker = len(available_devices)
>
> # Number of batches processed per job per worker
> batches_per_job  = gpus_per_worker * max(1, FLAGS.iters_per_worker)
>
> # Number of batches per global step
> batches_per_step = gpus_per_worker * max(1, FLAGS.replicas_to_agg)
>
> # Number of global steps per epoch - to be at least 1
> steps_per_epoch = max(1, model_feeder.train.total_batches // batches_per_step)
>
> # The start epoch of our training
> # Number of GPUs per worker - fixed for now by local reality or cluster setup
> gpus_per_worker = len(available_devices)
>
> # Number of batches processed per job per worker
> batches_per_job  = gpus_per_worker * max(1, FLAGS.iters_per_worker)
>
> # Number of batches per global step
> batches_per_step = gpus_per_worker * max(1, FLAGS.replicas_to_agg)
>
> # Number of global steps per epoch - to be at least 1
> steps_per_epoch = max(1, model_feeder.train.total_batches // batches_per_step)
>
> # The start epoch of our training
> self._epoch = step // steps_per_epoch
> ```
>
> So what happens is that your set-size during training differs from
>   your current set size. Thus the strange epoch number.
>
> Simplified example (without confusing batch size): If you once trained
>   5 epochs of a 1000 sample training-set, you got 5000 "global steps"
>   (persisted as a number in your snapshot). After this training you
>   change the command line parameters to a set of size 1 (your --limit_*
>   parameters). "Suddenly" you'll get displayed epoch 5000, because 5000
>   global steps means applying a data-set of size 1 5000 times.

Take away: use the `--checkpoint_dir` argument to avoid this kind of issues.